# How to setup AWS lambda deployment of a NestJS project with route 53 domain?

Tags: reactjs, lambda, nestjs, aws-api-gateway, serverless

## How to setup AWS lambda deployment of a NestJS project with route 53 domain?

I have a NestJS application.
The app is basically stock created with `nest new <app-name>`.

I've installed the `@nestjs/serve-static` because i want to serve my vite-react-typescript application with nestjs on AWS as a cheap deployment solution.

I've setup the scripts in a way that when i run `npm run build` in my NestJS project it builds my NestJS application alongside the vite-react-typescript application.

The NestJS build dir structure is something like this

```
dist/
   - auth/
   - client-dist/ # Client build directory
   - app.module.js
   - lambda.js # Handler method for lambda deployment
   - main.js
   - ...
```

This is my app.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, './', 'client-dist'),
      serveRoot: '/',
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [HealthcheckController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Also important to mention, i have configured the api prefix in `main.ts`

```js
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api', {
    exclude: [{ path: '/', method: RequestMethod.GET }],
  });
```

There are 2 endpoints on the api right now

- /api/status --> The healthcheck endpoint returning the app version and a timestamp
- / --> the endpoint on which the vite-react-typescript application is served

This is my vite.config.ts for local development

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "./",
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/": {
        target: "http://localhost:3000",
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

When i serve the app locally with Node it works as it should. `/api/status` returns the healthcheck response and `/` path returns the app

Now for the lambda part

This is my `serverless.yaml`

```yaml
service: my-api

frameworkVersion: '3'

useDotenv: true

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: eu-central-1
  architecture: x86_64
  endpointType: REGIONAL
  stage: development
  environment:
    API_PORT: ${env:API_PORT}
    API_PREFIX: ${env:API_PREFIX}
    API_ENVIRONMENT: ${env:API_ENVIRONMENT}
    DATABASE_URL: ${env:DATABASE_URL}
  
functions:
  api:
    handler: dist/lambda.handler
    memorySize: 512
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
              - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
            allowCredentials: false
```

The `serverless deploy` command ran successfully.

I have bought a domain, lets just say for now that the domain name is `my-app-domain.com`

This is my vite.config.ts that i configured for lambda deployment client build

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "./",
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/": {
        target: "my-app-domain.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Lets say this was my `lambda-deployment-url`: `https://abcdefghij.execute-api.aws-region.amazonaws.com/development`

In the AWS API Gateway console i configured the custom domain for the app. `my-app-domain.com` should point to `lambda-deployment-url` (example url of my lambda application).

The problem is that i cant configure the lambda deployment or API Gateway to serve the application when i hit the root of my-app-domain.com

The things that I've tried

1. Serving the application on the /app path (best and closest result i've had)

   - This returned the application only when i hit `my-app-domain.com/app/<some-random-string>` for some reason, the `/api/status` healthcheck endpoint worked normally
2. Creating subdomains, adding the custom domains to Lambda API Gateway and configuring the mappings

   - `api.my-app-domain.com` --> pointed to `https://abcdefghij.execute-api.aws-region.amazonaws.com/development/api`
   - `app.my-app-domain.com` --> pointed to `https://abcdefghij.execute-app.aws-region.amazonaws.com/development/app`
3. Modifiying my serverless yaml events

   ```yaml
   events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
              - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
            allowCredentials: false
      - http:
          path: /api/{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
              - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
            allowCredentials: false
   ```

   - the root path returned `json {"message": "Missing Authentication Token"}`, but when i hit `/app` again i get the application with failed imports in the console `GET https://my-app-domain/app/assets/index-6f2e35a7.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

...

The responses i get are

- `json {"message": "Missing Authentication Token"}`
- `json {"message": "Forbidden"}`

How to configure the domain to serve the applicaiton on the root path?